# Ignorar las { } en python3 (format)

Tags: python-3.x

Estoy teniendo un problema, y es con el format de python3, el problema es que no encuentro la manera de ignorar la llave "{}" quiero ignorar una llave pero quiero que la otra llave tenga el contenido que quiero imprimir, un ejemplo:

```
for i in range(10):
    print(f"{LOOP} En el loop... {i}")
```

En el ejemplo muestro como quiero imprimir el número que se esta iterando pero a la vez que ignore la primera llave ya que solo lo uso para imprimirlo, seria como un decorativo por así decirlo, como puedo lograr ignorar la primera llave? pero que a la vez que el segundo me lo capte?
Este es el error que me devuelve

```
NameError: name 'LOOP' is not defined
```

pero como ven en el código LOOP es solo la decoración del output.

Comment: ósea quieres imprimir la llave??

Comment: Exacto, pero cuando lo intento el format lo toma como que quiero imprimir una variable y no es así

Comment: Quiero imprimir la llave pero que dentro de ella este la palabra LOOP, quedaría: {LOOP} En el loop... 1, y así sucesivamente

Comment: solo haz `f"{{LOOP}} ....` utiliza nuevamente las llaves

Comment: Así podría escapar la llave?

Comment: sip, pon las llaves entre llaves `{{LOOP}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si quieres tomar las llaves `{}` como una caracter literal tendrás que escaparlo y algo *curioso* de los *f-stings* es que no permiten los *backslash* `\` por lo que no los puedes usar para escapar un caracter, ósea no puedes hacer `f"\{LOOP\}"`, esto provocará un bonito error :).

Entonces como puedes tomar como literal las llaves `{}`?, pues vuelve a utilizar las llaves

```
{{LOOP}}
```

Entre las llaves puede ir cualquier cosa, ya sea una variable, un string, un objeto, **cualquier cosa**. puedes hacer `f"{'hola'}"` y te imprimirá `hola` (ojo que aquí uso comillas simples para el string dentro de llaves). Prácticamente es lo mismo que hacer

```py
print("hola "+algo+" bye")
```

Donde se puede ver claramente que las llaves funcionan como formas de concatenar, los *f-string* se inventaron para hacer un poco más elegante la concatenación de strings con objetos.